# Dynamic multiline text for checkbox not aligned well in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to adding the dynamic checkbox to the layout. As long as the text of the checkbox is single line it is aligned correctly. But as my text it getting multi line it does not align properly and the text is also not completely shown. Please follow the fig for how it look like

[image]

The code i am writing is this

```
else if (answerType == Constants.ANSWER_CHECKBOX_TYPE) {

        final CheckBox[] rb = new CheckBox[noOfAnswers];
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfAnswers; i++) {

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
            SurveyAnswer answer = question.getAnswerList().get(i);
            rb[i] = new CheckBox(this);
            rb[i].setSingleLine(false);
            rb[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            rb[i].setText(answer.getAnsweText());
            rb[i].setTag(size);
            linear.addView(rb[i], params1);
            rb[i].setId(i + 1);
            rb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (isChecked == true) {

                        viewList.add(buttonView);
                    } else {

                        viewList.remove(buttonView);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this implementation I liked to go for the gridview implementation. By using the gridview and adding checkbox items in the grid I able to align it properly to the center.

Answer (score 0):

In html there is style option like style="float:left;"
This will align dyna..generated check boxes in straight.
try something like this over here .
try to set some style to this check box.